# Looping query through a column's data and getting the count ad-hoc

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table Transaction

```
Transaction
----------------
txn_id
txn_type
txn_time
txn_dt
txn_amt
```

Sample Data

```
Txn_id   Txn_Type Txn_Time  Txn_dt       Txn_Amt
1        M        11:00     10-Mar        500
2        M        11:10     10-Mar        100
3        V        11:20     10-Mar        200
4        P        11:30     10-Mar        100
5        P        12:45     10-Mar        200
```

The txn_type column can have values like 'V','M','P','X' etc.

I need to get the following output

```
Date     HR       Description         Count
---------------------------------------------
10-Mar   11       Visa                 1
10-Mar   11       MasterCard           2
10-Mar   11       PayPal               1
10-Mar   12       PayPal               1
```

Please note that V= Visa, P=PayPal, M= MasterCard, X=Others

Kindly guide me on how to achieve that? The tran_type can differ with each hour and each day. However, we need to find the different count of a particular tran_type per hour i.e. 11:00-11:59 etc. Looping through the various possibilities of tran_type in any hour and getting the corresponding count is the high level plan.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a `group by`, but exactly how depends on the datatype of txn_time.

Comment: ... And I you don't have a table that refer `Txt_Type` to `Description`, use `Case When`

Comment: The data type for txn_time is TIMESTAMP (6). 
I can create a table to define the transaction type and description, but would a group by bifurcate my results as Visa count is 1, Master card count as 2 as different rows of the query? Any heads up on how the new query should be?

Answer (score 0):

A `group by` should do the trick, something like this:

```
select txn_dt, trunc(txn_time, 'HH24') as hr, txn_type, count(*) as count
from transaction
group by txn_dt, trunc(txn_time, 'HH24'), txn_type
```